# Set Autolayout Constraints Relative to Device Size

Tags: objective-c, swift, autolayout

I fell into the trap of relying on Autolayout. I currently have a ViewController with a ton of UIViews and realized they're distorted on smaller devices (iPhone 4s and 5).

Is it possible to set constraints in Autolayout relative to device size.

**For example, I have one `UIView` with several other `UIViews` aligned edges. I would like to change the height in Autolayout of that one UIView to equal half the device height.**

Comment: "I fell into the trap of relying on Autolayout" -- it's not a trap, it's a very useful and powerful technology if you take the time to learn it properly.

Comment: I highly recommend learning how to work with constraints programatically. It is incredibly powerful and by far my favourite way to layout views (not that I am bashing storyboards they are great too).

Comment: As per my answer below - I use size class constraints as much as possible, but some things are tricky to achieve (but worth simplifying to find a good way to do it), and so I have developed a way to tweak one or two constraints (IBOutletted) programmatically as shown.  Some people swear by managing autolayout strictly programmatically, but probably starting with Interface Builder first and getting really comfortable with it is a better place to start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. There is a way to constrain by screen size.

They are called [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html).

In Interface Builder look on the bar at the bottom of the screen where it says **`wAny hAny`**, those are pulldowns. Select the combination of height and width of the device and orientation you want to constrain it to, and when you create the constraints in that mode, they'll be specific to that size/orientation.  You can also add and modify size-specific constraints in the inspector, constraint editor pane, in Interface Builder.

If you need to tweak some corner case things that you aren't able accomplish conveniently enough with size clases, you can make an IBOutlet for a constraint and refer to it in your code, and modify it when the view appears and changes, similar to the following example.  This is much easier and safer than trying to generate constraints from scratch programmatically.

Note: When modifying a NSLayout constraint via an IB outlet, you can only tweak the `constant` field, not `multiplier` because `multiplier` is readonly at runtime. So whatever scaling factor you use (if any) must be multiplied into whatever final value you use for constant.

```
@IBOutlet var tableYTopConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     adjustViewLayout(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size)
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        adjustViewLayout(size)
}

func adjustViewLayout(size: CGSize) {
    switch(size.width, size.height) {
    case (320, 480):                        // iPhone 4S in portrait
        tableYTopConstraint.constant = 0
    case (480, 320):                        // iPhone 4S in landscape
        tableYTopConstraint.constant = 0
    case (320, 568):                        // iPhone 5/5S in portrait
        tableYTopConstraint.constant = 0
    case (568, 320):                        // iPhone 5/5S in landscape
        tableYTopConstraint.constant = 0
    case (375, 667):                        // iPhone 6 in portrait
        tableYTopConstraint.constant = 0
    case (667, 375):                        // iPhone 6 in landscape
        tableYTopConstraint.constant = 0
    case (414, 736):                        // iPhone 6 Plus in portrait
        tableYTopConstraint.constant = 0
    case (736, 414):                        // iphone 6 Plus in landscape
        tableYTopConstraint.constant = 0
    default:
        break
    }
    view.setNeedsLayout()

}
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the answer. If I have both `wAny hAny` and `wCompact hCompact` constraints set, which would take precedent?

Comment: When you select w and h,  it presents a pop-up showing a rectangle in blue,.  In the text below that rectangle which depicts the orientation you selected, it describes which models and which orientations that combination of w and h applies to.  width doesn't take precedence over height or vice versa. Together they specify a specific size class

Comment: So i set constraints for a view in `wCompact hAny`. If I wanted to do this programmatically, would what be the equivalent?

Comment: App I've been developing uses IB based autolayout and it's not worth it to me in this app to dispense w/Interface Builder constraint creation and go programmatic. It *is* a good idea to learn 100% programmatic at some point & learn the autolayout symbolic language (as opposed to long function name/param lists) to create constraints.  Don't try to delete/interact w/ios generated constraints. You can disable those for a ViewController & create & manage your own. You can get very confused and create a lot of problems hacking constraints you didn't create except as shown in my answer above.

Comment: You saved me another few hours or days understanding the full picture of size classes and auto layout. I was running into edge cases using height spacing constraints and was looking for a way to handle the edge cases in the interface builder instead of programmatically. Thank you!

Comment: `Emma` you could try the new autolayout syntax with guidelines in iOS9. UIStackView is a new powerful view too. Also the main UIView inside your first ViewController is automatically constrained to the screen size. @nerdistcolony you could ease your code by using `fallthrough` from `iPhone 4S in portrait` to `iPhone 6 Plus in portrait`.

Comment: @DevAndArtist - nice!